# My Images and Text is not recognized by SEO Tools

Tags: seo, wordpress, web-development, analytics

I have a new website called http://appovete.com/

When I check with SEO Tools like http://www.seoptimer.com/ or WooRank I see this strange things:

**Images**: **83 images found**, 57 without ALT attribute - I have more than 100 articles with not less than 2 images in any article.

**Words and Chars**: 231 words with 6787 characters - The site have more than 100 articles, but here says only 243 words?

**Bolds: (Missing)** - I have bold text in every article.

My question is, why these tools don't find my images and text? Why I have so many characters but so much less words?

Please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you really trust these SEO tools sites? They are not always up to date. You should visit them as an informative way; don't change your pages because of them.

Comment: I will not. But tools like these two are trusted and 100% reliable and up to date tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool is not analyzing your whole website but the particular page you give it. So it doesn’t matter how many articles you have or how many images are in them, the fact is there are 83 images on your home page.

Same thing goes for “Words and Chars” and “Bolds: (Missing)”. Keep in mind seoptimer.com will only analyze the specific URL you give it, not the whole site.